# How to extract values of the current default palette in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a ggplot for which I'm using three specific colors from the `viridis` package.

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
iris %>%
    ggplot(aes(Petal.Length)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(alpha = 0.5), fill = viridis(3)[2]) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(y = 1), alpha = 0.5, width = 2, lwd = 1.5, fill = viridis(3)[3], color = viridis(3)[1]) +
    guides(alpha = "none")
```

Which produces this plot:
[image: plot]

My problem is that colors are hardcoded. On the one hand, I'm using the viridis color scale anyway, so the current code is redundant. Also, when I globally change the color scale, respectively don't set it to viridis in the first place, I need to change the code, which is cumbersome when it's called as a function from a package.

Hence, I tried to get access to the pallete to which ggplot2 defaults.
I looked into `getOptions()` and `palette()` but neither did what I wanted.
I also looked around but only found ways to access specific palettes.
Ideally, there is somthing like `current_default_palette(n)[k]` to set the colors manually.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: sorry that the image doesn't show (You need at least 10 reputation to post images.)

Comment: You can create a custom function `my_palette <- function(n) viridis(n)`, and pass it to your plots instead of directly passing `viridis()`. This way, to change palettes, you simply change the definition of `my_palette()` at the top of your code

Comment: This is actually already part of my (future) code. The problem is, I wanted it to come with the current globally set palette as a default value so I don't need to set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the code of `scale_fill_discrete()` you can see that it defaults (if `type` is not set when calling the function and the option "ggplot2.discrete.fill" is not set globally) to `scale_fill_hue`, so this may be what you're looking for:

```r
scale_fill_hue()$palette(5)
[1] "#F8766D" "#A3A500" "#00BF7D" "#00B0F6" "#E76BF3"
```

Similarly, `scale_colour_discrete` defaults to `scale_colour_hue` ...

---

I'm not sure if this helps, but you can retrieve information about the *specific* colours that ggplot is using (*not* the name of the palette) via `ggplot_build`.  If your current plot is saved as `gg0`, then

```r
ggb <- ggplot_build(gg0)
lapply(ggb$data, function(x) lapply(x[c("colour", "fill")], unique))
[[1]]
[[1]]$colour
[1] NA

[[1]]$fill
[1] "#21908CFF"


[[2]]
[[2]]$colour
[1] "#440154FF"

[[2]]$fill
[1] "#FDE725FF"
```

This is admittedly a little confusing, but:

- the first `lapply()` iterates across *layers* of the plot (each of which is a separate element of the `$data` element of the output of `ggplot_build()`
- for each layer, we extract the *unique* elements of the `colour` and `fill` columns. In your case the first element (the histogram) has only fill specified (so the colour column is all `NA`), while the second element (the bar) has both colour and fill specified.
  c

Comment: The first part I knew about, but it's just the standard default mode, not the current one (set via global options). However, the second part let's med build the current palette via: `x <- c(1, 2, 3)`, `y <- c("a", "b", "c")`, `palette_plot <- bind_cols(x, y) %>% ggplot(aes(x)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = y))`, `palette_plot <- palette_plot %>% ggplot_build()`, `lapply(palette_plot$data, function(x) lapply(x["fill"], unique))[[1]]$fill[1]`. Now I just need to wrap this in a function :) Seems a bit hackish, but it works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify aesthetic defaults:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# cehck default aesthetics, geom_histogram uses the same aes as geom_bar
GeomBar$default_aes
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `colour`    -> NA
#> * `fill`      -> "grey35"
#> * `linewidth` -> 0.5
#> * `linetype`  -> 1
#> * `alpha`     -> NA
GeomBoxplot$default_aes
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `weight`    -> 1
#> * `colour`    -> "grey20"
#> * `fill`      -> "white"
#> * `size`      -> NULL
#> * `alpha`     -> NA
#> * `shape`     -> 19
#> * `linetype`  -> "solid"
#> * `linewidth` -> 0.5

# update:
update_geom_defaults("bar", aes(fill = viridis::viridis(3)[2]))
update_geom_defaults("boxplot", aes(fill = viridis::viridis(3)[3], color = viridis::viridis(3)[1]))

# check updated values:
GeomBar$default_aes$fill
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^viridis::viridis(3)[2]
#> env:  global
GeomBoxplot$default_aes
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `weight`    -> 1
#> * `colour`    -> `viridis::viridis(3)[1]`
#> * `fill`      -> `viridis::viridis(3)[3]`
#> * `size`      -> NULL
#> * `alpha`     -> NA
#> * `shape`     -> 19
#> * `linetype`  -> "solid"
#> * `linewidth` -> 0.5

iris |>
  ggplot(aes(Petal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(alpha = 0.5)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = 1), alpha = 0.5, width = 2, lwd = 1.5) +
  guides(alpha = "none")
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info, it will streamline some things for me considerably. Also, it's a work around I could use, so you get an upvote (which I can't do because of lack of reputation...). Still, it doesn't actually answer my question, so I'm hoping for someone else to chime.